# Adding unit tests for javascript in a C++ project

Tags: javascript, c++, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working on a C++ codebase and I use CPPUnit as the unit testing framework. recently I added to the project a javascript browser addin that communicates with an external process using native messaging port.

I want to add unit tests for the javascript addin code and mock out the native messaging port. can I somehow do it from CPPUnit by wrapping the javascript code without setting up a new javascript unit tests framework? what are my options?